# Is it legal to use variables in a closure before declaring them with let or const in an outer scope?

Tags: javascript, closures, ecmascript-6

A piece of code like the one below runs flawlessly both in Firefox and Chrome.

```
function A() {
    console.log(message);
}

let B = function () {
    console.log(message);
};

let message = 'Hello, World!';

A();
B();
```

Anyway, [JSHint](http://jshint.com) complains about the `message` variable being used before declaration.

> 'message' was used before it was declared, which is illegal for 'let' variables.

Is it really illegal to use a variable declared with let or const in an outer scope inside a closure when the declaration follows the closure block, or is JSHint going nuts?

Comment: Don't know about the downvote, but here's [a bit of MDN that is relevant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone_and_errors_with_let).

Comment: Potentially, `A` or `B` *could* be called before the assignment to `message` happens, in which case you would indeed get an error.

Comment: @FelixKling True. Anyway, if `A` or `B` are called before the assignment to `message` but after its definition, no error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in your case using a variable defined by using `let` is fine. But in other cases it causes problem. For example,

```
console.log(x); let x = 10;
```

Will throw you a reference error. Because `x` got created but not initialized. This is not like a normal variable definition which uses `var`. `let` declarations will not be `initialized` until the the statement with `let` got executed. Hence JSHint complains you about your code in a generic way.

Comment: `let` and `const` are hoisted as well, but their are not initialized, hence the error.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for pointing out my misunderstanding on that. Can you point me to a relevant link? It was throwing reference error, So i just thought in that way. How hoisting is happening with `let` and `const`?

Comment: See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation. Step 27c creates bindings for `var` declararions and initializes them with `undefined`. Step 35 creates bindings for `let` and `const` but does not initilize them. You could also test it this way: `let foo = 42; { console.log(foo); let foo = 21; }`. This will still throw a reference error because the inner declaration shadows the outer one, but it's not initialized yet.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks again. Seriously I am learning a lot from you now a days. :) Edited my post.

Comment: Always happy to help :)